# powershell copy files into remote machine issue using Copy_Item cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I was trying to copy few files into my remote box, but i see the path format is not correct issue, can someone chekc this?

```
for($hostname in Get-Content C:\folder1\machine.txt){
Copy-Item -Path "C:\folder1\ramen-0.1-web-1.3.6.jar" -Destination "\\hostname\C:\folder1\folder2\" -Recurse -Force

}
```

Error Message is:
Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing **'$'** sign. Your are using **'c:'** as part of your **destination path**.

```
for($hostname in Get-Content C:\folder1\machine.txt){
Copy-Item -Path "C:\folder1\ramen-0.1-web-1.3.6.jar" -Destination "\\hostname\C$\folder1\folder2\" -Recurse -Force

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If powershell remote is enabled, here's another way (foreach not for) (-recurse doesn't make sense for a file):  -ToSession can't be an array.

```
$list = Get-Content C:\folder1\machine.txt
$sessions = new-pssession $list
foreach($session in $sessions){
Copy C:\folder1\ramen-0.1-web-1.3.6.jar C:\folder1\folder2 -ToSession $session -For
}
```